# Some Questions About the Java Sound API

Tags: java, api, audio, javasound

I'm relatively new here and to the usage of Java's Sound API and audio programming altogether. I have been wondering if it's possible to do the following things with Java's Sound API:

- extract the values of individual frequencies an audio file consists of. (ex: amplitude for frequency range 20Hz-20kHz)
- based on those values, perform manipulations, then write a new modified audio file.

If you're wondering why I'm asking these, I'm planning to create a custom audio compression format with the use of a swarm-based optimization algorithm. So for those who can give a more straightforward answer: would creating an audio compression program be possible using Java's Sound API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> ..I'm planning to create a custom audio compression format .. would creating an audio compression program be possible using Java's Sound API?

Quote from the [JavaSound info.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) page here at SO.

### Service Provider Interface

The Java Sound API uses a Service Provider Interface to identify encoders & decoders for sound formats and sequence types. This way, adding support for a new format or type is as simple as providing a decoder and/or encoder for it, adding an SPI file to the manifest of the Jar it is in, then adding the Jar to the run-time class-path of the application.

---

So if you can provide the encoder/decoder, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly read the waveforms.  I.E., for a 44.1 kHz file, you could read 44,100 different sample values per second.  I don't know that the Java Sound API will calculate audio frequencies for you, but if you're already going to be performing manipulations, you can probably calculate whatever you need yourself.

A few years back, I had used something along these lines to decode a suspect SMPTE time code signal, printing out the various bits and fields.  (Basically, I just had to track whenever the value crossed 0, and for how long.)

In short, yes, creating an audio compression program would certainly be possible - though I know many people who would be surprised at the choice to do this in Java.